# Pushing elements inside an array in a loop, when I dont push one element, all the rest appear as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, array-push

I have a for loop and an array and I want to push a new element in to the array when it meets a certain condition, in this case `i!=5`, when the program doesn't push an element in the array, because of that condition, the remaining elements tu push appear as undefined.

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = [];
  var sh_test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var dataRange;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i != 5)
      array.push(i);
    dataRange = sh_test.getRange(i + 1, 10);
    dataRange.setValue(array[i]);
  }
}
```

I expect the output

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
and so on...
```

But I get

```
1
2
3
4
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
and so on...
```

What is it that I am not seeing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect to get `5` in the output? That's the value you're skipping with `if (i != 5)`.

Comment: Yes you are right,I don't expect that output, I didn't notice I wrote that, I wrote it too quickly, thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to update the question to show what you really meant.

Answer (score 1):

You do `dataRange.setValue(array[i]);` however after the first `i!=5` array doesnt have that many elements for `array[i]` to be defined. In short the value of i increases with each iteration of the loop, but the number of elements does not. You could perhaps just use array length to access the last element.

```
for (var i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   if (i!=5)
   array.push(i);
   dataRange = sh_test.getRange(i+1,10);
   dataRange.setValue(array[array.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `i` is in the range `0` to `4`, `array.push(i)` assigns `i` to `array[i]`. But after you skip `i == 5`, the array indexes are off by 1. When `i == 6`, `array.push(i)` assigns it to `array[5]`, and there's nothing yet in `array[6]`. This goes on for the rest of the loop: the `push()` function assigns to `array[i-1]`, but you use `dataRange.setValue(array[i])`, and `array[i]` hasn't been set yet. So you get `undefined` all those times.

It's not clear what you're really trying to do here, but you can simply do

```
dataRange.setValue(i);
```

to get the current index of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your function:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i != 5)
      array.push(i);
    dataRange = sh_test.getRange(i + 1, 10);
    dataRange.setValue(array[i]);
  }
```

is the same as:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i != 5){
      array.push(i); // <-- array doesn't grow when i == 5
    }
    dataRange = sh_test.getRange(i + 1, 10);
    dataRange.setValue(array[i]); // <-- array[i] is increasing even when the array doesn't grow
  }
```

You could only set the values in the case were `i != 5`

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = [];
  var sh_test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var dataRange;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i != 5) {
      array.push(i);
      dataRange = sh_test.getRange(i + 1, 10);
      dataRange.setValue(array[array.length - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
0
1
2
3
4

6
7
...
19
(Total of 20 lines with a blank line where 5 would be)
```

OR, if you want the last item  displayed TWICE:

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = [];
  var sh_test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var dataRange;
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (i != 5)
      array.push(i);
    dataRange = sh_test.getRange(i + 1, 10);
    dataRange.setValue(array[array.length - 1]);

  }
}
```

Gives:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4
6
7
...
19
(Total of 20 lines)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It was a dumb mistake, and you help me to find it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var array=[];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clear();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,10,20,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(i!=5) {
      array.push(i);
      vA[i][0]=array.join(',');
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```